# Create list of the Nth elements of input list

Tags: haskell

Bear with me as I am new to Haskell.

I'm trying to write a function that outputs:

> The first list in the output should be the same as the input list. The
>   second list in the output should contain every second element from the
>   input list and so on.

example: `func "ABCD" = ["ABCD","BD","C","D"]`

I started by writing a function to get every nth element of a list:

```
everyN n xs = case drop (n-1) xs of
                [] -> []
                (z:zs) -> z : everyN n zs
```

Now I know that I just need to have a function which calls this function and increments the `n` value each time it is called, but I can't for the life of my think about how to write such a function or what would be the most concise way to express it. If possible I'd like to not use explicit recursion and use a haskell language function.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Surely you can dream up a title which concisely summarizes your question.

Comment: The title is too generic to attract potential answerers. As a suggestion, try to generalize/adapt `[everyN n "ABCDEFGHI" | n <- [1..9]]`. Alternatively, use `map` instead of list comprehensions.

Comment: can you explain to me how i might use map in this scenario?

Comment: i have never seen the syntax "| n <- [1..9]" before.

is that line saying, call everyN for each value of n from 1 to 9?

Comment: @leshow - yes exactly it says: make me a list (`[ .. ]`) where we generate the items of this list by `everyN n xs` and we take `n` from `1..9`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's kindof lame as @chi already gave you the comment - but maybe as a bonus I have an alternative for your `everyN`:

```
everyN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
everyN n xs = every n xs
  where every _ [] = []
        every 1 (x:xs) = x : every n xs
        every m (_:xs) = every (m-1) xs

seqN :: [a] -> [[a]]
seqN xs = [ everyN n xs | n <- [1..length xs] ]
```

Here is the same using map (again as @chi mentioned):

```
seqN' :: [a] -> [[a]]
seqN' xs = map (flip everyN xs) [1..length xs]
```

#### explanation

Someone asked me to explain this a bit:

First look at map: `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` - now clearly we want to fit in `everyN` and as `everyN` has *two arguments* we surely want to partial apply it to something. The argument that is changing is not the input-list `xs` but the `n` - the `xs` will stay constant.

So surely we want to partial apply `everyN` to `xs` - but we cannot as this argument is in the wrong place.

`flip` to the rescue: this *flips* the arguments of `everyN`:

```
flip everyN :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
```

and we can partial apply this to `xs` and write:

```
flip everyN xs :: Int -> [a]
```

and finaly we can use this with `map` (of course ranging `n` over `1 .. length xs` - because if we make jumps longer than `length xs` there will be nothing left to pick) as shown.

How do put this into one english sentence I don't know ;)

Comment: could you write out what "map (flip everyN $ xs) [1..length xs]" would sound like in english? Sorry I don't follow what that line is saying.

Comment: How would you write the map line without using the function application ($)?

Comment: just with one more parenthesis pair: `map ((flip everyN) xs) [1...length xs]`

Comment: You do not need to use `$`: `(flip everyN xs) == ((flip everyN) xs) == (flip everyN $ xs)`. (And no, I do not mind at all that you expanded my comment into an answer.)

Comment: thanks lol. 

I guess the part I was confused about was the number of arguments. map takes a function and a list, everyN takes an int and a list, however I can't see from:

`map ((flip everyN) xs) [1..length xs] `

it reads to me like everyN is only getting passed a list, i don't see where the integer is getting passed. and which argument is getting passed to the map function as a list?

Comment: thanks I get it now. you partially apply the function everyN on the list when you pass it to the map function. cool!